# React-native Google Cast Library

Tags: google-cast, react-native, react-native-ios

(this is probably a stupid question, but here goes..)

I've been trying for some days now at having a go at creating a integrated cast that works with react-native, but can't get it working.

Is there any easy way of integrating the cast library with react-native, any go-to examples like the CastHelloText-Android for example?

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [react-native-google-cast](https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast) library that unifies both android and iOS chromecast sdk.

**For iOS**

- This library requires Cocoapods to manage Chromecast SDK.
- Add pod `google-cast-sdk` to your Podfile. This is the easier way to have the SDK up to date.

**For Android**

- This library requires Google Play Services, Media Router and Google Cast dependencies to manage Chromecast SDK.
- You need to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.4.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.1'` into your your app's `build.gradle` dependencies. `mediarouterversion` must match with your `appcompat` version.

Refer to the [example folder](https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast/tree/master/example) to find an implementation of this project. Use `pod install` and `react-native link react-native-google-cast` to try it.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work with custom receiver apps, nor being able to send messages on a custom namespace.